# Ruby on Rails 3.1 Blog Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-engines

I see a lot of people asking about Blog Engines, but most of the questions & answers are rather old.  Or if they aren't old most of the projects are old.  I'm wondering if anyone knows of any Blog Engines that currently support Rails 3.1 or are at least being actively developed to support Rails 3.1.

I would also be interested in seeing any sample applications or blog posts written for Rails 3.1 Blogs.  I am going to be adding a blog to one of my websites, and would prefer to simply use a Rails Engine or sample code if there are any good ones out there. I hate reinventing the wheel.  Looking for something simple, and not too opinionated so I can modify easily to suit my own needs.

Answer (score 4):

you might want to check out Refinery http://refinerycms.com/engines

doesn't look like they are 3.1 yet, but probably soon

https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-blog

Comment: I have previously looked into refinery, and found it to be pretty nice.  I just had to make a real simple website from some provided html/css, and found that it was overly cumbersome to work it into refineries structure.  Perhaps I just wasn't familiar enough with customizing Refineries looks, but it was taking me far longer to customize Refinery than it did to just setup a Rails app form scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would probably be to use [Typo](http://fdv.github.com/typo/).

Typo is currently using rails 3.0.9. Rails 3.1.0 is still a release candidate so I don't know of any blogging apps using it right now. If you must use rails 3.1.0 then you may have luck grabbing the gem for 3.1.0.rc4 (the newest version) and using typo anyway. Chances are everything will still work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Typo looks great, but it is a standalone application.  I'm more interested in an Engine that I can add on to an existing application.  Thanks for the recommendation though I think it will be a good code sample to review.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. I don't know of a gem like that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Enki is a good fit, currently at Rails 3.0 but there is a github branch with Rails 3.1 support.
http://www.enkiblog.com/

Comment: Hi charlysisto, you're right here's a 'real' rails3 blog engine http://rubygems.org/gems/jabe

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly BrowserCMS was recently made to be a mountable engine: https://github.com/browsermedia/browsercms/commit/6098699fed2e3dbd65815ac3a5ce0dd6acc103d2

Seem to have a bit of time and experience behind them.  More akin to Concrete5 with an inline front end / in context editing facility for users, which can be a real plus.

Answer (score 0):

I`m looking into this now and I`m getting to conclusion that the best way to do this would be mounting a rack-app(like sinatra) into your rails app, there's various basic sinatra blogs in github to start or copy, not to mention this is fully customizable and I guess very light-weight.. engines will likely have dependencies and may also break when updating gems, a rack app won`t

I wasn't able to find any satisfying solution with engines

other stuff I found:

mounting a rails app inside a rails app: http://blog.dynamic50.com/2010/02/22/rails-3-0-mount-multiple-apps-as-engines/ feels a bit weird(heavy?), but you could mount a fully featured app like enki...

http://planscope.io/blog/2012/03/08/mounting-a-blog-within-a-rails-3-application/ this blogpost talks about using Toto, it seems pretty nice, easy and simple... but the project is not being maintained and it doesn't seem to be able to support a lot of features...
I dunno about using git to post, it makes it really simple but I dunno if I'd like having non-code stuff in my commits

Answer (score 0):

Monologue https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue . From their web:

It is a barebone blog engine for Rails. It is built as a Rails engine and with a focus on keeping very few dependencies to ease it's use in your project. You can also use monologue-markdown which will replace the default editor with a simple Markdown editor.

Seems like pretty active development also.