# Embed Blog in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, blogs

I have a Ruby on Rails application and want to include a blog inside the application.

I was wondering what's the best way to do that. I don't want to have a link to an external blog. I want the blog integrated in my application. Also i don't have the time to programm the blog functionality. I want to use existing solutions.

What's the best way to accomplish that? Any recommendations? What are the best solutions?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to include one application within another is by using engines. This might help you [Ruby on Rails 3.1 Blog Engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741172/ruby-on-rails-3-1-blog-engines)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Typo](http://fdv.github.com/typo/) would address your needs installed as a Rails Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has done it so far I need to mention here that the spirit of Rails is to make everything friendly enough so that you can code your own.

It's a bit more work but then your blog module fits right in with the rest of the app.